# High-latency anonymous communication minimum delay?

Tags: protocol-design, anonymity, mixnets

High-latency anonymous communication (e.g. Mixmaster and Mixminion) delay messages for a long time using mixers to anonymous communications. I understand that it has applications for email and p2p but not for good for responsive applications such as web browsing and instant messaging.

I've gone through the papers for them but couldn't find the relevant information.

1. How long exactly are the delays? minutes, hours, days?
2. Can these be set? is there a minimum bound for it to be defined as safe? I asked this because I'm wondering if it could be somehow applied to web browsing